# error java application jar jasperreport, jpa and hibernate

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm working with jpa 2.0, hibernate and jasperreport with NetBeans as IDE. I'm using apache poi to import and export some info from excel too. It works fine in NetBeans, but when I build it and try to generate the report for the jar I got an error that I'll show bellow.

jars in project:

```
antlr-2.7.6
antlr-2.7.7
asm
asm-attrs
cglib-2.1.3
commons-beanutils-1.8.0
commons-collections-2.1 (for jasperreports)
commons-collections-3.1 (for hibernate)
commons-digester-2.1
commons-javaflow-20060411
commons-logging-1.1.1
dom4j-1.6.1
ehcache-1.2.3
groovy-all-2.0.1
hibernate3
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final
hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
hibernate-tools
iText-2.1.7.js2
jasperreports-5.5.1
jasperreports-fonts-5.5.1
jasperreports-javaflow-5.5.1
javassist
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final
jgoodies-common-1.2.0
jgoodies-looks-2.4.1
jta
junit-4.6
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin
org-apache-commons-logging
oscache-2.1
png-encoder-1.5
poi-3.7-20101029
slf4j-api-1.6.1
slf4j-simple-1.6.1
```

Sorry for so many jars, but isn't a small application.

here my method to generate the report

```
public void crearInformeCuentas(TableModel modelo, String titulo, String cobrado, String cobrar) {
Map parametro = new HashMap();
parametro.put("tituloPrincipal", titulo);
parametro.put("cobrado", cobrado);
parametro.put("cobrar", cobrar);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    parametro.put("titulo" + i, modelo.getColumnName(i));
}
try {
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = 
            RXmlLoader.load("C:\\Escribania\\informeCuotasPagadasEnElDia.jrxml");
    JasperReport informeCuentas = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JRTableModelDataSource jrtmd = new JRTableModelDataSource(modelo);
    JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(informeCuentas, parametro, jrtmd);
    JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jPrint, false);
    view.setTitle("Comprobante de pago de una cuota");
    view.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    view.setVisible(true);
} catch (JRException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
JasperPrint jasperPrint = new JasperPrint();
}
```

here i call the method to show the report from tablaInformePagos:

`crearInformeCuentas(tablaInformePagos.getModel(), titulo ,montoCobradoTF.getText(), montoCobrarTF.getText());`

this is the error that i got:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:Error compiling report java source files:C:\Users\Matias\report32name_1398367817150_601730.java C:\Users\Matias\report32name_Table32Dataset321_1398367817150_601730.java C:\Users\Matias\report32nae_dataset1_1398367817150_601730.java
```

the jrxml files are in C:\Escribania\

eg: C:\Escribania\informeCuotasPagadasEnElDia.jrxml

I think that this is all. If i miss some important information feel free to ask about it. Any help or advice about it or how to solve the problem will be really appreciated. Sorry for any grammar error, this isn't my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a JDT compiler jar to your application's classpath.  You can find one in the JasperReports distribution.

Also, jasperreports-javaflow-5.5.1 is a variant of jasperreports-5.5.1 so you only need one of the two.  Go with the plain jar if unsure.

Comment: Deleting the jasperreports-javaflow-5.5.1 file it isn't giving me any warning for two equal components now. But, adding the jdt-compiler-3.1.1 the error is still there. Thanks for answer. Sorry if i'm late, i was working all morning